# Prove that if $E(X\log X)<\infty$ then $E(\sup_n |S_n|/n)<\infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

This is part 2 of a two part question. In the first part, we were asked to show that if you had a non-negative sub martingale $M_n$ then $$\sup_n E(\sup_{k\leq n} M_k)\leq \sup_n 2E(M_n \log M_n)+2$$

We need to use the above fact to Prove that if $E(X\log X)<\infty$ then $$E(\sup_n |S_n|/n)<\infty,$$ where $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$, with $X_i$ iid with distribution $X$.

I am unsure of how to introduce a sub-martingale into the problem since $S_n/n$ is not a martingale. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know backwards martingales?

Comment: yes, so we have that $S_n$ is a backwards martingale, so $S_-n$ is a martingale and thus we can use the first part. But then we are bounded by $2E(|S_n|\log|S_n|)+2$. Clealy I have to use the fact that $E(|X|\log|X|) is finite to justify the upper bound is finite. I am having difficulty with part.

Comment: ^I meant $S_n/n$ is a backwards martingale.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $(S_n/n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a backwards martingale.
2. Applying the first part to the (backwards) martingale gives a bound in terms of $$\mathbb{E}\left(\left| \frac{S_n}{n} \right| \cdot \left|\log\left( \frac{S_n}{n} \right) \right| \right).$$ In order to show that this expression is finite, use that $$[1,\infty) \ni x \mapsto x \log(x)$$ is a convex function and $$(0,1] \ni x \mapsto x \cdot \log(x)$$ is bounded.

Comment: you mean than $S_n/n$ is a backwards martingale correct? Also I dont see how convexity helps. Jensen's inequality says that $\varphi(E(X))\leq E(\varphi(X)$.

Comment: @kjashl Ah, sorry, I used $S_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ instead of $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. And no, this is not about Jensen's inequality. Note that the convexity of $x \log x$ implies $$\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right) \log \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right) \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \log (x_i)$$ whenever $x_i \geq 1$.

Comment: Why do we need to show that $(S_n/n)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is a backwards martingale?

Comment: @2pirsquared In order to apply the inequality from the first part, we need that $|S_n/n|$ is a submartingale... this follows if we can show that $S_n/n$ is a martingale