# If $E(|X|\log|X|)<\infty$ then is $E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{n}\ \log\left(\frac{|S_n|}{n}\right)\right]<\infty$?

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to finish a homework problem in my probability class. I think I am at the end of my problem if I can show that  $$E(|X|\log|X|)<\infty$$ implies that  $$E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{n}\ \log^+\left(\frac{|S_n|}{n}\right)\right]<M$$

For all $n$, where $S_n$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables with distribution of $X$. $\log^+x=\max(\log x,0)$.

I am not sure if this is true but I feel like it should be. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: $$|S_n|/n\leqslant\max|X_k|\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n|X_k|\qquad \log(|S_n|/n)\leqslant \log\max|X_k|\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\log|X_k|$$

Comment: Im sorry i guess I should have been more specific, is it uniformly bounded in $n$?

Comment: Indeed this is not the same question at all. Then the convexity of $x\mapsto x\log x$ is your friend...

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I have been trying to use convexity, but I am not sure how. All I know is Jensen's inequality but that says for a convex function $\varphi$ we have $\varphi(E(X))\leq E(\varphi(X))$. If we have $\varphi=x\log x$ then we are intrested in bounding the righthand side, and jensen is not helpful.

Comment: $$\varphi\left(\frac{|S_n|}n\right)\leqslant\varphi\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n|X_k|\right)\leqslant\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\varphi(|X_k|)$$

Comment: In other words, we are not using Jensen on the expectation with respect to $P$, but on the summation over $n$ (which is really integration with respect to the probability measure $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \delta_k$).

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128636/